# How do FOEs respawn?

Tags: etrian-odyssey-untold

I've cleared B2F-B6F of the dungeon, and noticed that certain FOEs (the Ragelope) on B2F have started respawning after a period of time. Looking through my Monstrous Codex I noticed I missed an item from Fenrir, the boss on B5F, and so I wonder if FOEs like him, and others will respawn, and if so, how long do I have to wait?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FOEs respawn **every 3 full days**. Bosses like Fenrir respawn **every 7 days**. Also, don't go for that item from Fenrir. It's a conditional drop that requires you to kill him on turn 1.

Comment: Rather "don't go for it now". It is easier to achieve later on.